# insert to specific index for mongo array

Tags: mongodb

Mongo supports arrays of documents inside documents. For example, something like

```
{_id: 10, "coll": [1, 2, 3] }
```

Now, imagine I wanted to insert an arbitrary value at an arbitrary index

```
{_id: 10, "coll": [1, {name: 'new val'}, 2, 3] }
```

I know you can update values in place with $ and $set, but nothing for insertion. it kind of sucks to have to replace the entire array just for inserting at a specific index.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Starting with **version 2.6** you finally can do this. You have to use [$position](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/update/position/) operator. For your particular example:

```
db.students.update(
  { _id: 10},
  { $push: {
     coll: {
       $each: [ {name: 'new val'} ],
       $position: 1
     }
  }}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will do the trick:

```
var insertPosition = 1;
var newItem = {name: 'new val'};

db.myCollection.find({_id: 10}).forEach(function(item)
{
    item.coll = item.coll.slice(0, insertPosition).concat(newItem, item.coll.slice(insertPosition));
    db.myCollection.save(item);
});
```

If the `insertPosition` is variable (i.e., you don't know exactly where you want to insert it, but you know you want to insert it after the item with `name = "foo"`, just add a `for()` loop before the `item.coll =` assignment to find the insertPosition (and add 1 to it, since you want to insert it AFTER `name = "foo"`.

Answer (score 1):

Handy answer (not selected answer, but highest rated) from this similar post:
[Can you have mongo $push prepend instead of append?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131957/can-you-have-mongo-push-prepend-instead-of-append)

utilizes $set to insert 3 at the first position in an array, called "array".  Sample from related answer by Sergey Nikitin:

```
db.test.update({"_id" : ObjectId("513ad0f8afdfe1e6736e49eb")}, 
                 {'$set': {'array.-1':     3}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your comment:

Well.. with concurrent users this is going to be problematic with any database...

What I would do is the following:
Add a last modified timestamp to the document. Load the document, let the user modify it and use the timstamp as a filter when you update the document and also update the timestamp in one step. If it updates 0 documents you know it was modified in the meantime and you can ask the user to reload it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the $position operator this can be done starting from version 2.5.3.

It must be used with the $each operator. From [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/update/position/):

```
db.collection.update( <query>,
                  { $push: {
                              <field>: {
                                         $each: [ <value1>, <value2>, ... ],
                                         $position: <num>
                              }
                           }
                  }
                )
```