# Can you have mongo $push prepend instead of append?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'd like to have push add at the beginning of my set rather than appended to the end when I do a mongo $push.

Is it possible to do an atomic push update that adds elements as the first rather than the last?

---

**2014 update**: [yes you can](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/position/).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094573/use-mongodb-array-as-stack#comment12929388_10094573

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i add a value to the top of an array in mongodb?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936019/how-do-i-add-a-value-to-the-top-of-an-array-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As of MongoDB v2.5.3, there is a new `$position` operator that you can include along with the `$each` operator as part of your `$push` query to specify the location in the array at which you would like to insert a value.

Here's an example from the docs page to add the elements 20 and 30 at the array index of 2::

```
db.students.update( { _id: 1 },
                    { $push: { scores: {
                                         $each: [ 20, 30 ],
                                         $position: 2
                                       }
                             }
                    }
                  )
```

Reference: http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/update/position/#up._S_position

Comment: Indeed, this will be nice once they push the 2.6 stable release.

Comment: The `$push - $each - $position: 0` syntax is awkward. Please help [implement $unshift by voting on this issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19974).

Comment: Also only works for update, right? Adding a NEW item into the array won't work.

Comment: Do I _have to_ use `$each` when I prepend _a single value_ to an array?

Comment: @КонстантинВан "To use the $position modifier, it must appear with the $each modifier." Source: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/position/

Comment: Is this faster than, in some x programming language, finding and retrieving the array from Mongo, manually prepending the array, and then fully replacing/updating the Mongo array?

Answer (score 30):

Use negative index with $set for prepend, tested in mongo v2.2:

```
> db.test.insert({'array': [4, 5, 6]})
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("513ad0f8afdfe1e6736e49eb"),
  "array" : [ 4, 5, 6 ] }

//prepend 3
> db.test.update({"_id" : ObjectId("513ad0f8afdfe1e6736e49eb")}, 
                 {'$set': {'array.-1':     3}})
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("513ad0f8afdfe1e6736e49eb"), 
  "array" : [ 3, 4, 5, 6 ] }

//prepend 2
> db.test.update({"_id" : ObjectId("513ad0f8afdfe1e6736e49eb")}, 
                 {'$set': {'array.-1':     2}})
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("513ad0f8afdfe1e6736e49eb"), 
  "array" : [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ] }

//prepend 1
> db.test.update({"_id" : ObjectId("513ad0f8afdfe1e6736e49eb")}, 
                 {'$set': {'array.-1':     1}})
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("513ad0f8afdfe1e6736e49eb"), 
  "array" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ] }
```

Comment: Is there a way to set multiple valuesat the begining of the array?

Comment: Great workaround.  Looks like mongo 2.6 (stable) will include a non-work around.

Comment: How would you unshift several elements at once atomically?

Comment: Btw, is this feature documented somewhere?

Comment: does this still work? I keep getting " MongoError: Cannot create field '-1' in element"

Answer (score 6):

A similar question was asked a few days ago.  Unfortunately, the short answer is, "no", but there is an open request for this feature.
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2191 - "$push() to front of array"

There is some more information as well as a possible work-around on the other thread:  "Use MongoDB array as stack" - [Use MongoDB array as stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094573/use-mongodb-array-as-stack)

Hopefully the above will be useful and help you to find an acceptable work-around.

Comment: Aha.  Looks like Chris Shain beat me to the punch!  I did not see the comment before I posted.

Comment: @Monkey: Since v2.5.3, you can use the `$push - $each - $position: 0` syntax. Can you please update the accepted answer? Also, since that syntax is awkward, please help [implement $unshift by voting on this issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19974).