# Check first value in array, insert new conditionally

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have an array of "states" in my documents:

```
    {
    "_id: ObjectId("53026de61e30e2525d000004")
"states" : [
    {
        "name" : "complete",
        "userId" : ObjectId("52f4576126cd0cbe2f000005"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("53026e16c054fc575d000004")
    },
    {
        "name" : "active",
        "userId" : ObjectId("52f4576126cd0cbe2f000005"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("53026de61e30e2525d000004")
    }
]
   }
```

I just insert a new state onto the front of the array when there is a new state.  Current work around until mongo 2.6 is released here: [Can you have mongo $push prepend instead of append?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131957/can-you-have-mongo-push-prepend-instead-of-append)

However I do not want users to be able to save the same state twice in row.  I.E. if its already complete you should not be able to add another 'complete' state.  Is there a way that I can check the first element in the array and only insert the new state if its not the same in one query/update command to mongo.

I say one query/update due to the fact that mongo does not support transactions so I don't want to query for the first element in the array then send another update statement, as that could cause problems if another state got inserted between my query and my update.

Answer (score 1):

You can qualify your `update statement` with a query, for example:

```
db.mydb.states.update({"states.name":{$nin:["newstate"]}},{$addToSet:{"states":{"name":"newstate"}}})
```

This will prevent updates from a user if the `query` part of the `update` returns no document. You can additionally add more fields to filter on on the `query` part.