# Push to last element of sub-array

Tags: mongodb

My document looks like this:

```
{
  _id: ...
  checkins: [
    {...}
    {...}
    {
      ...
      activities: [
        {...}
        {...}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If I want to push into the first element of the `checkins` array I could do this:

```
mycol.updateOne(
            {'_id': ...},
            {'$push': {
                'checkins.0.activities': entry}}
        )
```

But I need to insert `entry` into the last index of the checkins array, so how could I implement something like this?

```
mycol.updateOne(
            {'_id': ...},
            {'$push': {
                'checkins.-1.activities': entry}}
        )
```

Edit:

I can't just do:

```
'$set': {'checkins.-1': <entry>}
```

Because it'd overwrite the other elements in the array, and this:

```
'$set': {'checkins.-1': [...otherEntries, entry]}
```

Would mean inserting the whole array every single time, and since it's very big array, it'd be way too expensive

This, as suggested, looks promising, though:

```
{
  $each: [ entry ],
  $position: -1
}
```

But this just lets me push into the `checkins` array, if I wanted to add an element to the `activities` subarray it'd involve inserting the whole array, just like the first solution. In this case, I'm looking for something like this:

```
{
  $each: { '$push': {'activities': entry} },
  $position: -1
}
```

But of course it does not work, mongo complains that

> The argument to $each in $push must be an array but it was of type: object

How do I push into the last element, i.e. into `checkins.-1.activities`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you have mongo $push prepend instead of append?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131957/can-you-have-mongo-push-prepend-instead-of-append)

Comment: Not quite, the syntax doesn't work the same when dealing with nested arrays. Also, I'd rather not $set the entire activities array every time I need to push one activity

Comment: Nested arrays are really bad. Basically impossible to atomically update before relatively recent changes for MongoDB, and mostly they just don't deliver as a structure what you "think" you designed them for. Typically people think "like a relation", but it's not actually how you do it. The `-1` problem has long be dealt with by basically *"reversing the order of the array"*, which is the **real** use case of `$position` and `$sort` modifiers. You would be better of actually showing you full use case, since the **solution** would certainly be to "flatten" the arrays and reverse the order.

Comment: In other words "show what actually needs to get done" rather than discuss how you think it needs to be done. And be prepared to make structural changes to data.

Comment: _show what actually needs to get done_ Its literally in the two examples. I had to add why they don't work because the site prompted me to add why the suspected dupe isn't a dupe.  _Typically people think "like a relation"_ that's totally not what I think, please if you need more info ask for it but don't start a discussion. _The -1 problem has long be dealt with by basically "reversing the order of the array"_ So, how does one reverse the order of an embedded array within another array? Or use `$position` and `$sort` within arrays?

Comment: I've updated the question and hope it's clearer now